# Android Studio -- Active Button when click checkbox

Tags: android, button, checkbox, android-studio

I have a terms of use section in my application and I want to activate a button when a user checks a checkbox.

Comment: if your checkbox isChecked, enable button, else disable it.set button's listener on your Main class's oncreate() method. Android studio has to nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {      
    protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {          
    super.onCreate(icicle);           
    setContentView(R.layout.content_layout_id);           
    final CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkbox_id);          
    final Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_id)

    checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener(){
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
            boolean isChecked) {

            if (buttonView.isChecked()) {              
                    b.setEnabled(true);
            } else {
                    b.setEnabled(false)   
            }

        }

    });
}  
}
```

Comment: I don't see the point of doing this, it will always produce the same result, and won't change the button state when checkbox state changes.

Comment: can you explain more , please

Comment: Of course ;) This code will only be executed once, when the Activity is created, so calling checkBox.isChecked() in onCreate will always return false which is the default value. In order to change the button state depending on the checked state of the checkbox, you would need to attach a OnCheckedChangeListener so a callback is activated whenever the user presses the checkbox. I hope that's clear enough, let me know if you need further explanation ;)